# Problem with a query in MySQL which filters out records that I want to show

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this schema:

```
visits
---------
id              INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
clients_id      INT
date            DATETIME
status          TINYINT

clients
--------
id              INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name            VARCHAR(200)
```

And these data

```
id  name
1   John Snow
2   Ned Stark
3   Cercei Lannister
4   Daenerys Targaryen

id  clients_id  date       status
1   1           2019-10-19  1
2   1           2019-10-20  1
3   4           2019-10-22  1
4   3           2019-10-23  0
```

I need to get all the clients, alongside the number of visits they had. However, I can't list client Cercei Lannister, since her visit was deleted (status=0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT visits.id) as number_of_visits 
FROM clients 
LEFT JOIN visits ON visits.clients_id = clients.id 
WHERE 
visits.status IS NULL OR visits.status = 1
GROUP BY clients.id;
```

This is the SQL TEST:
https://sqltest.net/#822790

What should I do to have her listed with 0 visits? `visits.status IS NULL` allows me to filter Ned Stark in, which has no visit.

Comment: Do you mean `coalesce(COUNT(DISTINCT visits.id), 0)`?

Comment: @jarlh It wasn't related to COALESCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) as number_of_visits 
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     visits v
     ON v.clients_id = c.id AND v.status = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Note that I replaced the `SELECT *` with `SELECT c.*`.  It only makes sense to select columns from the `clients` table.

If `id` is unit in `visitors`, then you don't need `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(v.id) as number_of_visits
```

This should be faster.

Finally, this is a case where a correlated subquery is likely to be faster with the right indexing:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM visits v
        WHERE v.clients_id = c.id AND v.status = 1
       ) as number_of_visits 
FROM clients c ;
```

The index is `visits(client_id, status)`.  This is faster because it avoids the aggregation on the full result of the `JOIN`.

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thank you! You may want to edit the answer because there's a semicolon before the GROUP BY